# Do v-for only when there are data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So in my Vue I have the following code

```
        <div v-if="titles!=null" >
          <div v-bind:key="chart.id" v-for="chart in titles.titles"> 
            <DataInfo v-bind:chart="chart" /> 
          </div>  
        </div>
```

In the `DataInfo.vue` file I have the `chart` I bind, as a prop.

My problem is that the `titles`comes form a GET request , so its not always availabel as soon as the page loads, so in the `DataInfo.vue`, the `chart` prop is also not always available, resulting in errors.

How can I have this `v-for` executed only when the `titles` is not null ? The `<div v-if="titles!=null" >` does nothing for now.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it's null and not undefined or anything else? it will probably work if you use v-if="titles" instead of v-if="titles!=null"

Comment: Is this a typo `v-for="chart in titles.titles"` or `titles` is an array inside another `titles` object?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div v-if="titles" >
      <div :key="chart.id" v-for="chart in titles.titles"> 
        <DataInfo :chart="chart" /> 
      </div>  
 </div>
```

and declare a data titles set to null, and when you get your ajax response assign the resulting datas to your titles variable

```
data(){
  return { 
    titles: null
  }
}
```